# Oozie coordinator creates 12 workflow jobs for one action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

guys.

I am using Hortonwork's HDP Sandbox. I've configured the simple spark job (which takes text file and outputs into another file the word counts).

Anyway, the problems I have is with the coordinator (in oozie), when I schedule the job to always repeat after 5 minutes. 
Each time the coodrinator creates 12 same workflows and I don't know why. 
Here is my coordinator configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.5" end="2020-01-02T17:53Z" frequency="${coord:minutes(5)}" name="Simple Spark Scala Coordinator" start="2019-05-01T17:53Z" timezone="GMT+04:00">
    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>/user/admin/tmp/workflow.xml</app-path>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

and here is the workflow configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="Spark Scala Example Workflow">
    <start to="spark_scala_example"/>
    <action name="spark_scala_example">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/tmp/result_large"/>
            </prepare>
            <master>local</master>
            <name>Spark Scala Example Action</name>
            <class>com.example.App</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/tmp/spark-scala-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
            <arg>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/tmp/test_large.txt</arg>
            <arg>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/tmp/result_large</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Do you guys have any idea why it creates 12 copies of the same workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if the date in all those 12 workflows is the same?

If you choose to set the start date in the past, Oozie will compensate for the missing workflows.
Not sure why only 12

Comment: Yes, I've specified the start date before the current one. Is that a problem? I'll try to specify the current date then.

Comment: Seems like that they are still 12 :( each time it starts.

Comment: Oh no, my mistake. the 12 ones this time are the future jobs :)